# Task management software with cards, pictures&files, notifications, checklists, deadlines, labels

Tags: knowledge-base, task-management, help-desk

We are looking for a new task management software, that could ideally also be used as a helpdesk and knowledgebase software.

At the moment we are using OneNote to create and manage our tasks

- (+) with OneNote you can create really great tasks. you can add pictures easily, move them around, create text that belong to that image etc., also responding / commenting to a task can easily be done with pictures etc.
- (+) you can also easily add local files or links to local files. This is also a big pro for us.
- (-) you have no way of being notified that something has been added to a task that you sent to someone. that is a big contra for us. we have almost 50 big OneNotes for our projects, in each there are 3 - 8 people working in it. You have to be reminded by someone "Hey, I just added something to OneNote Task #1089, can you review it?" and that makes it really unmanageable

I also tried Trello, Kantree and Microsoft Planner

- (+) I love the "card" philosophy of these programs. it's a much better overview than some big OneNote Tables. Also you can do anything you want with these cards. you can create a helpdesk board and create helpdesk cards there, you can create a knowledgebase board and create knowledgebase cards there. very nice principle.
- (+) You can get notified easily. You have a calendar for each board and you get a notification when something changed on a card where you're working on
- (+) You can use checklists, deadlines, labels etc. which makes it very manageable.
- (-) None of them has a good editor like OneNote. Especially not Trello that has just a markdown editor. you can not easily work with pictures, you can not as easily build a new task for someone.
- (-) It's all in the cloud and you have no way (or no easy way at least) to link local files without uploading them to a cloud
- (-) Some of them are Browserapps, with no desktop app.

As you can see, there are points on both types of applications that are very good, but also a lot that are very bad.

I'm looking for a taskmanagement software that combines these attributes:

- Having an Editor like in OneNote to easily add pictures, text in different colors, etc.
- Having the possibility to link to local files
- Having a way to get notified if something changed on a task you're on or you sent to someone
- Good overview on all tasks of a project (maybe also in card principle like in Trello). Ideally also with a calendar.
- Possibility of using this software also as helpdesk and knowledgebase.
- easy to use. In our company everyone will use this software. meaning not just IT-people, also older people and people from completely different professional genre like carpenters or electricians.
- available in German language

Is there something like this on the market? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Please remove all mentions of "OneNote" and "Trello" from your question. Instead, describe only the features you need.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul why?

Comment: See https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ok i will change that but i need some time for that, will do it till monday

Comment: I use [workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) for knowledge basis, [tedegraph](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph) for incremental reading and [anki](https://ankiweb.net) for memorization of information. For task management I use [list.it](https://welist.it/).

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we use [bitrix24](https://www.bitrix24.com/) it is generally a task management software.

For managing task some of its advantage are you can:

- Assign a observer
- Set deadline
- Set priority

Apart from that it comes with calendar, kanban notes, scrum board etc.

You can create workgroup, create drive space and get notifications for things.

You can use giphy also in chat just like slack.

It has web version, desktop app and mobile app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend Teamhood, as it is visual and easy to use for both task and project management. However, task editing may not be something that suits your style of work. Then again, most task management solutions would not be as flexible as a note-taking app.

In any case, here is a post comparing different [task management tools](https://teamhood.com/project-management/task-management-tools/) as well as specifying which features they offer. That should be of use when researching something similar.